# How to "Get Quotes" for all currencies and stocks for a specific day (GNU Cash)

Tags: gnucash

How can I tell GNU Cash to **update its Price Database** for all known currencies, stocks, bonds, mutual funds, etc **for a *specific* day**?

I'm trying trying to prepare a report for a date in the past. I've [set the `Options` for the report to `nearest in time`](https://gnucash-docs-rst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/C/ch_invest.html?highlight=price%20database#the-price-source-in-reports) so that it will grab the prices for the commodities from the Price Database that are closest to the date of the report as possible.

Well, I checked the Price Database, and I have gaps in the prices for some of my stocks. For many stocks, I don't have any prices defined for the day of the report. Therefore, my report may be inaccurate.

I know that I can go to `Tools` -> `Price Database` and click the `Get Quotes` button. This will fetch the current quote (price) and add it to the Price Database for all defined currencies, stocks, bonds, mutual funds, etc. But that will fetch and add the prices for *today's date* only.

How can I do the equivalent of `Get Quotes` but for a specific day in the *past*?

Comment: See also https://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2015-April/059746.html

Comment: See also https://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2022-December/104492.html

Comment: See also https://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2018-August/079430.html

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem. I use the gnucash python bindings and the
following script, to import prices from a text file which has date
(YYYY-MM-DD) and price with a new date on each line.

Hope it could be some use. Best wishes.

```python
import datetime
from gnucash import Session, Account, Split, GncCommodity, GncPrice

url = "personal.gnucash"

# Initialize Gnucash session
session = Session(url, True, False, False)
book = session.book
pdb = book.get_price_db()
comm_table = book.get_table()

# Define commodities
sec_gbp = GncCommodity(book,"Pound Sterling", "CURRENCY", "GBP", "826", 100)
sec_chf = GncCommodity(book,"Swiss Franc", "CURRENCY", "CHF", "756", 100)

def extractFXrateFromFile(filename,book,pdb,sec_base,sec_curr):
  with open(filename) as myFile :
    for line in myFile.readlines() :
      splitLine = line.split(' ')
      y,m,d = (int(x) for x in splitLine[0].split("-"))

      price = GncPrice(book)
      price.set_time64( datetime.datetime(y,m,d) )
      value = price.get_value()
      value.denom = int( 1e10 )
      rate = float(splitLine[1])
      value.num = int( rate * 1e10 )
      price.set_value(value)
      price.set_currency( sec_curr )
      price.set_commodity( sec_base )
      pdb.add_price(price)

extractFXrateFromFile("chf_per_gbp.txt", book, pdb, sec_chf, sec_gbp)

session.save()
session.end()
session.destroy()
```